# Desarrollo de patrones con C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, poo, patrones-de-diseño

Me pasaron un programa en C# en POO, tengo mis nociones de que son clases y objetos, pero quería saber porque en *PRODUCTOMODEL* primero instancia *`Producto pro=new Producto();`* y luego crean Producto **p** para después igualar.

Después observo que en *frmPRODUCTO* hacen **pr = model.find();**.

No logro entender el porque hacen esas cosas *(quizás esta mal implementado, pero si compila)*, no sé si será diseño de patrones.

Este es el código:

**CLASE PRODUCTO**

```
public class Producto
{
    // propiedades
    public string IdProducto { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public decimal Precio { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    //constructor
    public Producto()
    {
        IdProducto = "P001";
        Nombre = "Producto Inicial";
        Fecha = DateTime.Now;
        Precio = 120.50M;
        Cantidad = 100;
    }
```

**CLASE PRODUCTOMODEL**

```
public class ProductoModel
{

    Producto pro=new Producto();

    //constructor
    public ProductoModel()
    { 
    }
    // metodos para procesar
    public void create(Producto p)
    {

        pro = p;

    }

    //public Producto find()
    //{
    //    return pro;
    //}
    public Producto find(Producto o)
    {
        return pro;
    }
```

**frmPRODUCTO**

```
public frmProducto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    // instanciar objeto de la clase productocontroller
    ProductoController obj = new ProductoController();
    Producto pr=new Producto();
    ProductoModel model = new ProductoModel();


    private void btnMostrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pr = model.find();

        lblIdproducto.Text = pr.IdProducto;
        lblNombre.Text = pr.Nombre;
        lblFecha.Text = pr.Fecha.ToShortDateString();
        lblPrecio.Text = pr.Precio.ToString();
        lblCantidad.Text = pr.Cantidad.ToString();
        //pr = model.find(pr);
    }

    private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // asignar valores al objeto pr
        pr.IdProducto =""+ txtIdproducto.Text;
        pr.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
        pr.Fecha = dtpFecha.Value;
        pr.Precio = decimal.Parse(txtPrecio.Text);
        pr.Cantidad = (int)numCantidad.Value;
        // registrar producto
        model.create(pr);
        txtIdproducto.Text = pr.IdProducto;
        MessageBox.Show("Producto registrado con exito", "exito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Producto pro=new Producto();
```

y

```
pro = p;
```

Lo hacen para poder usar el Producto `p` que pasan como parámetro en toda la clase. Ya que la variable `pro` tiene alcance en toda la clase por estar declarada dentro de su contexto.

```
pr = model.find();
```

Lo único que hace es retornar el Producto que está en la instancia `model`. 
Si te fijas bien está mal esa parte, ya que la función `find()` necesita de un parámetro, y en esta parte del código la llaman sin pasarle el parámetro.